# How to use ajax call for deleting database rows and updating the table in the page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a table in my page that its content is filled based on database entries. I use **foreach loop** to iterate through the database rows and fill the table. The last column has delete button which is shown in each row. This button deletes that specific row from the table.

```
int i = 1;    
foreach (var item in Model.messages as List<Message>)
    {    
    <tr>
            <td>@i</td>
                                                                
            <td>@dConverter.DateConverter(@item.messageDate.ToShortDateString())</td>
                                                                
            <td>@dConverter.GetTime(@item.messageDate.ToString())</td>
            <td>@Model.usersList.First(x => x.Id == item.senderId).department</td>
            <td>
                <a href="" class="message-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-@i">Open Message</a>
                <input type="hidden" id="msg-id-@i" value="@item.messageId"/>
            </td>
            <td><a type="button" style="color: red" class="message-link" id="del-@i">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
i++;
    }
```

I want to use ajax calls to do this task:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#del-@i').on("click", function(){
            var msgId = $('#msg-id-@i').val();
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("messageId", msgId);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Messages/DeleteMessage",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData,
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.success){
                        alert("The selected message removed.");
                    }else{
                        alert("Error!");
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code for the action that do the deleting task is:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeleteMessage(int messageId) 
        {
            bool response = _messageRepository.DeleteMessageById(messageId);
            if(response == true)
            {
                return Json(new { success=true});
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { success=false });
            }
        }
```

The problem is that when I press the button, nothing happens. I tried to debug the action in controller and saw that this action is not called when I press the button. There may be a matching error in **ids** between javascript and the razor codes. How can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like your id's in your javascript will not match any buttons//

Comment: @Steve0 yes, and I don't know how can I make them matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the `ids` listed in the javascript are not going to contain the correct value of `i` as the generation of the script does not occur in the `for loop`.

** this answer leverages the jQuery Selector [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest-selector)

Here are the changes I would suggest;

1. add an attribute to the row with the ID in it.

```
    <tr msg-id="@item.messageId">
```

2. change your js to determine the row of the button clicked and extract that Id.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.message-link').on("click", function(){
            var msgId = $(this).closest("tr").attr("msg-id");
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("messageId", parseFloat(msgId));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Messages/DeleteMessage",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData,
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.success){
                        alert("The selected message removed.");
                    }else{
                        alert("Error!");
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is there any way to hide the message id column from the user? I want to hide it because each user will see their own messages and message ids will not have any order.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after with this comment, from what I have seen in the code provided the Id's are in the source code and not rendered visibly on the interface

Comment: I meant `<tr msg-id="@item.messageId">`. You suggested to add message Id in the table, but the user will see this id.

Comment: if you just add it as an attribute on the row the user will not `see` the id.  that is what I meant not to add a new column or something.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.